# IBM SPSS Statistics 28 fails to open in macOS 12 (Monterrey)

Tags: crash, macos

IBM SPSS Statistics crashes immediately after opening the application. The error message in the Apple Crash Report is "stats quit unexpectedly".

I followed the advices [here](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/discussion/spss-28-not-opening-on-macos-monterey-124) and [here](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/discussion/can-not-startup-spss-statistics-premium-gradpack-28-on-macos-monterey-124), but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts, the solution I found was to run SPSS with sudo from the terminal:

```bash
sudo -b "/Applications/IBM SPSS Statistics/SPSS Statistics.app/Contents/MacOS/stats"
```

To facilitate the execution of SPSS in this condition, it is convenient to create a shell script that can be executed by double-clicking on it in Finder (a .command file). To create the script in your Desktop, follow these steps:

1. Open Terminal
2. `cd ~/Desktop`
3. `echo 'sudo -b "/Applications/IBM SPSS Statistics/SPSS Statistics.app/Contents/MacOS/stats"' > SPSS.command`
4. `chmod a+x SPSS.command`

Now you can double-click the file `SPSS.command`, enter your password and SPSS will open.